# Dynamic subreport in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

I would like to set up a dashboard report in SSRS that contains a bunch of sub reports, but have the reports that are displayed be configurable at run time.

I.E. there could be 4 parameters which represent the names of 4 reports. The report contains 4 reports, and the name of each sub report should be taken from one of the parameters.

It looks like I can't do this, as the 'Use this report as a subreport' property is a dropdown and doesn't provide a way of configuring it as an expression.

Am I right?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 3):

I figure your scenario is just to display one at a time. I needed to do almost the same thing. I have a main report in which I wanted a dynamic number of different subs to be displayed. I solved it like this:

- A main report (Main) with a tablix containing a subreport (SubMain), the dataset for Main passes id, subid and subtype. SubMain has no dataset.
- And directly in the SubMain I added all my subs (SubDetail) which have their own dataset.
  And then I set visibilty for SubDetails depending on type.
  /Erik

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd have to define each subreport in the main report and then set visibility. Or use drill through to emulate navigation.