# conditional loading of subreports in a Microsoft ReportViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a set of about 15 local reports that show up in a user properly designed user control. However, for the purposes of emailing / saving / printing we have included respective RDLCs with static content and datasets and parameters to control the dynamic data.

There is a Consolidated report that is generated and this is not displayed anywhere but just exported. The `ReportViewer` component for this report has a `ConsolidatedReport.rdlc` file that references different `SubReports`. Everything works fine here till we had a request to generate reports in Spanish.

So to display reports in Spanish, we made code changes and for the static content we included another set of 15 RDLCs each corresponding to its English version. These changes worked seamlessly as well.

However, these things fail miserably when it comes to exporting the `ConsolidatedReport.rdlc` which shows up the English content only irrespective of the language chosen by the user. I have handled the SubReportProcessing Event to correctly get into the subreports loading.

However, I do not know how shall we force the subreports section to load the Spanish language `.rdlc` file instead of the default English language. I have also looked at the `DrillThrough` event option as well, but I am not able to find out a way to trigger it and also appropriate sequence to handle it. I have also looked into the `(LocalReport)e.Report.LoadSubReportDefinition(...)` call as well. Need some help working this out.

Thanks,
Bhushan.

Comment: Its been a while I have worked with SSRS, but I think you can send in a language as a parameter in your consolidated report and then decide which report needs to be loaded

Comment: Consider posting the bit of code that is not working.

Comment: @Nilesh Is it going to change my Subreport RDLC if I Add a condition based on a Language parameter? I want to conditionally preload the English or Spanish RDLC before the subreportprocessing event is triggered so that the data from the dataset is added into the right report format / language before the entire report is rendered. Is there a report viewer event that allows me to handle the loading of the right rdlc of my choice on invoking it from subreport? Thanks.

Comment: @TomAranda ...Thanks for consideration and reading through the query. As far as code is concerned, the existing code consists of a simple boiler plate code which is similar to the code available at - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.subreportprocessing.aspx

Comment: Can you do something that is mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492599/use-expression-to-dynamically-decide-which-subreport-to-open)